# Three-plate capacitor

Tags: homework-and-exercises, capacitance

[image]

What is the total capacitance of this capacitor? Is it analogous to the case of inserting a plate into a capacitor (essentially creating two capacitors in series)?

Answer (score 1):

It is essentially two capacitors in parallel.  It will therefore have twice the capacitance than if everything else were held constant and one of the +Q plates were removed.